# apply syntax highlighting to a piece of text which may contain codeblocks

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, svelte

I have a string of text, this string is multiline and it may contain a code block enclosed within triple backticks. It may also have an inline code string. The location of these code blocks is not known (it may be at the end of string or in the middle of string), the language of these code blocks is known. For example:

````markdown
This is normal text
```
if __name__ == __main__:
    print('hello')
```
````

How can I apply syntax highlighting to the code block while keeping the normal text outside of syntax highlighting. Essentially I want it to look like, how this question looks like on the stackoverflow, with code block in a separate block. I would also like to add a copy button to the code block and show the language of code block.

(I am using svelte and tailwindcss for the front end)

What I have already tried:

1. I have tried `markdown-it` package with `highlight.js`. This does most of the part, somehow the code comes out without syntax highlighting (my guess is there is some clash between `highlight.js` css classes and `tailwind` css classes). Also this generates the whole thing in single component, which makes it difficult to separate out the code block to further customise it.
2. I also looked into `CodeBlocks` from `skeletonui` but it expects the only the code string and not the normal text. And I couldn't figure how to separate normal text from code text without knowing the location of latter in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Would approach it like this:

- Parse it as Markdown using some library, this should convert it to HTML of some form. If you need syntax highlighting that probably has to be configured in this step, you also may have to add the language to the fences, e.g.: ```` ```python ````
- If you only have an HTML string, convert that to DOM nodes, e.g. using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).
- Traverse the resulting DOM structure to modify it, code blocks should usually end up in specific elements (`code`/`pre`), maybe you can already make the Markdown parser attach particular classes. This should enable you to add additional text or elements. Standard functions like `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` should help here.
- Insert the result into the document.

  - On the client you can get an element reference via `bind:this` or [an action](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-action).
  - For SSR, you would have to convert the result back into HTML so it can be injected via `{@html ...}`